# Flutter Flame How to Update Overlay

Tags: flutter, flame

In Flutter Flame, I have an overlay expressed by a widget. I wish to rebuild the widget whenever the dependency changes, but I'm unclear how to do this in Flutter Flame.. there seems to be no mention of this in the documentation anywhere. How do I do this?

Reviewed the Flame documentation but it is not mentioned.
My only solution is to make an "update" widget that I run whenever update in the game is called.. then I call setState on the widget. Very hacky and non-performant!

```
late UpdateComponent t;
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();

   t = UpdateComponent(
     (p0) {
       setState(() {});
     },
   );
   widget.game.add(t);
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
   widget.game.remove(t);
 }
```

Comment: When you say dependency here, do you mean a component or something else? Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get my flutter overlay to call setState every time an element in Flame Game changes

Comment: And what do you mean by every time an element changes? Every time something moves position, scales, rotates, changes color or text etc? If you describe your use-case it will be easier to come up with a good solution for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a state management package from Flame in order to stream in-game changes. There are [flame_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flame_bloc), [flame_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flame_riverpod), among others.